# AnalysisException: cannot resolve given input columns:

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am running in to this error when  I am trying to select a couple of columns from the temporary table.

```
pd_df = pd.read_sql('select * from abc.cars limit 10', conn)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("cars_tmp")
df.show()

print('***************')
print("Reading from tmp table")
data = spark.sql('select location_id from cars_tmp')
data.show()


AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`location_id`' given input columns: [cars_tmp.abc.product_id, cars_tmp.abc.location_id ...]
```

When I select all the columns I get the results. So this is successful:

```
data = spark.sql('select * from cars_tmp')
data.show()
```

I tried below queries but they fail as well with the same error:

```
data = spark.sql('select cars_tmp.abc.location_id from cars_tmp')
data.show()

data = spark.sql('select cars_tmp.location_id from cars_tmp')
data.show()

data = spark.sql('select abc.location_id from cars_tmp')
data.show()
```

I am running these in datbricks.
Databricks runtime version: 7.0
Apache Spark version: 3.0
scala: 2.12

or "spark_version": "7.0.x-scala2.12",

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try ‘cars_tmp.abc.location_id’. Ie with backticks to escape the name. You could also try print(data.columns) to get the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by add each column in the panda select query. So something like this:

```
pd_df = pd.read_sql('select id, location_id, product_id from abc.cars limit 10', conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

The column name does not exist in the table. `select * from cars_tmp` works because you do not specify the column name.

Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64042756/8913402 with the same error handling.