# Cannot resolve 'column_name' given input columns: SparkSQL

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple piece of code here:

```
query = """
    select id, date, type from schema.camps
"""
df = spark.sql(query)
```

I get an error that says:

```
>     > "cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns:
>     > [ecs_snapshot, ecs_version, ecs_bundle_type]; line 2
```

File
>     > "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line
>     > 767, in sql
>     >     return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)   File
>     > "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>     > line 1257, in **call**
>     >     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
> line 69,
>     > in deco
>     >     raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve
>     > '`id`' given input columns: [ecs_snapshot,
>     > ecs_version, ecs_bundle_type]; line 2 pos 11;"

Tried everything I could based on the solutions provided. Funny part is I have another query on another table that works just fine. Would appreciate any help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the schema of the table:

```
camps(
    
    id numeric(38,0) NOT NULL encode raw,
    name varchar(765) NULL encode zstd,
    type varchar(765) NULL encode zstd,
    YYYY varchar(765) NULL encode zstd,
    ZZZZ varchar(765) NULL encode zstd,
    LLLL varchar(765) NULL encode zstd,
    MMMM numeric(38,0) NULL encode zstd,
    NNNN  varchar(765) NULL encode zstd,
    date timestamp without time zone NULL encode zstd,
    PPPP numeric(38,0) NULL encode az64,
    PRIMARY KEY (marketplace_id, campaign_id)
)
```

;

Comment: ads.dim_campaigns - do you can show describe?

Comment: @mvasyliv added there schema here

Comment: excuse me. schema of table dim_campaigns with database ads?

Answer (score 1):

The `camp.campaign_id` column does not exist in the table `ads.dim_campaigns`

This query works

```py
>>> l = [[1],[2],[3]]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['col_1'])
>>> df.createOrReplaceTempView('table')
>>> query = """SELECT table_alias.col_1 FROM table table_alias"""
>>> spark.sql(query).show()
+-----+
|col_1|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+
```

This query gives the same error as yours (please see the `col_x` instead of `col_1`)

```
>>> l = [[1],[2],[3]]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['col_1'])
>>> df.createOrReplaceTempView('table')
>>> query = """SELECT table_alias.col_x FROM table table_alias"""
>>> spark.sql(query).show()

/.../
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`table_alias.col_x`' given input columns: [table_alias.col_1];
```

Comment: It does exist. Please check the schema above that I added

Comment: It is very interesting! Is the table `ads.dim_campaigns` the same as `dim_campaigns` ? What I can see is that in the table you query you have only such columns camp.ecs_snapshot, camp.ecs_version, camp.ecs_bundle_type . 

Could you please tell what output you see from this query:
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM ads.dim_campaigns").printSchema()

Comment: @DigvijaySawant I'm happy we found the problem. Once you know why it happened, would you mind sharing the knowledge? Maybe at some time I will also have such issue...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try run code and show result.

```
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = spark.table("ads.dim_campaigns")
df1.printSchema()
// Please, show result

val df2 = df1.select(
  'campaign_id,
  'external_id,
  'start_date,
  'program_type,
  'advertiser_id
)
df2.printSchema()
// please, show result
```

Comment: Yes, Please, check. If you need in help, please go. Thank you.